# C++ Video streaming and transimisson

Tags: c++, video, network-programming, video-streaming, vi

I am new to video decoding/encoding. Currently I have a task to test the video transmission for a network coding. The network coding programme was already done.

Firstly I tried to divide the video into frames in opencv, and transmit the frames, but after division, I found a 3MB video are converted to 80MB total size frames!! which is not efficient for transmission. Is there any better way to do the video transmission? Can any pros provide me a sample code in C++? I be told that cannot directly put video into buff due to the transmission bandwidth limitation. I am wondering using the inter frame difference to reduce the transmission file size but I do not know ht to do this in C++.

Here is my code for video divide into frames.

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

VideoCapture cap("/home/yonghao/Documents/50MbitMJPEG1080p.mp4"); // open the video file for reading


double fps = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS); //get the frames per seconds of the video
int numFrames = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT); // get the total number of frames

 cout << "Frame per seconds : " << fps << endl;
 cout << "Total Frame Numbers : " << numFrames << endl;

namedWindow("MyVideo",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window called "MyVideo"

int frame_number = 1;

while(frame_number<=numFrames)
{
Mat frame;

bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame); // read a new frame from video

if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
{
    cout << "Cannot read the frame from video file" << endl;
    break;
}

    imshow("MyVideo", frame); //show the frame in "MyVideo" window

//save frame

    stringstream ss;
    string name = "/home/yonghao/Documents/Frames/frame_";
    string type = ".jpg";

    ss<<name<<(frame_number)<<type;

    string filename = ss.str();
    ss.str("");

imwrite(filename, frame);

cout << "Frame " << frame_number << " has been generated." << endl;

frame_number++;

//user exit by press ESC button

if(waitKey(30) == 27) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30 ms. If 'esc' key is pressed,    break loop
{
        cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
break;
}
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi. What you ask is very specific (so probably nobody here has sample code for your particular problem). Usually, if you ask a question it is _you_ who should provide the sample code, not us (because otherwise anybody answering has to guess, which wastes the time and effort of the people who want to help you). Either way, your question is too broad / ambiguous. (Voted to close).

Comment: sry im really new to here, I will try modify my questions.

Comment: I suggest looking into MPEG-TS and multimedia libraries instead of OpenCV.

Comment: What operating system(s) your application supports?

Comment: I currently work on Linux system, sry for the late reply.

Answer (score 2):

If the bitrate of your video is too high for your bandwidth, you need to recompress it, using a standard video codec, for example h264.
You can do that with the ffmpeg program, using something like :

```
ffmpeg -i <your_input_file> -c:v libx264 -crf 22 video.avi
```

This will encode with default options and a constant quality (crf parameter, the lower the higher quality), see [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for the options of h264 encoder, in your case you may prefer to use constant bitrate instead of constant quality.

Reading the video at correct speed and streaming it on the network would be possible in c with libavformat library (part of ffmpeg libraries), but probably complex for a beginner.

One simpler solution would be to pipe the output of a ffmpeg command to your program that does the network coding.

For example:

```
ffmpeg -re -i input.avi -f rawvideo -c:v copy pipe:1 | ./network_encode
```

This will read the encoded video file and send the raw video stream to your network encoding program (here network_encode read data from standard input, apply your network coding and send it)

On the receiver, you can do something similar to visualize your video (here network_decode receive the data from the network, decode it, and write result to standard output):

```
./network_decode | ffplay -i -
```

Comment: Thank you very much Adrien! this is exactly the answer for my question, I will try it out.

Comment: The code u showed me is the command line in ffmepg right? Due to I need to do the compression in c++, i searched something like this http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/encoding-example_8c-source.html, can I use this to do the video compression?

Comment: This is a starting point if you want to do it in c++, see also http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/transcoding_8c-example.html for a more complete example . However, this will be much more complex, time consuming, and less flexible to do it that way, so make sure you have a very good reason to do so (especially for the compression part, i hardly see what can be your reason given the information you give in the question)

Comment: This is my final year project actually, we are testing a kind of network coding, my task is convert a video to the packet and then apply the network coding algorithm to do a real time video transmission. We want to make the video transmission more efficient.