# C++ ffmpeg real-time video transmisson

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, video-streaming, real-time

I am a student currently working on my final project. Our project is focusing on new type network coding research. Now my task is to do a real-time video transmission to test the network coding. I have learned something of ffmepg and opencv and have finished a c++ program which can divide the video into frames and send it frame by frame. However, by this way, the transmission data (the frames)size are quite much more than the original video file size. My prof advise me try to find the keyframe and inter frame diff of the video (mjpeg format), so that transmit the keyframe and interframe diff only instead of all the frames with large amount of redundancy, and therefore reduce the transmission data. I have no idea in how to do this in c++ and ffmpeg or opencv. Can any one give any advice?
For my old program, please refer to here. [C++ Video streaming and transimisson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27836059/c-video-streaming-and-transimisson)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend against using ffmpeg/libav* at all. I would recommend using libx264 directly. By using x264 you can have greater control of NALU slice sizes as well as lower encoder latency by utilizing callbacks.

Comment: I am very new to this area, I have downloaded and installed libx264 as u mentioned, but how to use it to create a c++ program?

Answer (score 0):

Two questions which already may help yourself:

How are you interfacing from c++ to ffmpeg? ffmpeg generally refers to the command line tool, from c++ you generally use the individual libs which are part of ffmpeg. You should use libavcodec to encode your frames and possibly libavformat to packetize them into a container format.

Which codec do you use?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I plan to use H.264, encoding the existing video file to H.264 then transmit. Ya I notice people usually use ffmepg command line, I choose ffmepg is just because the function of that command line is exactly what I want in my program. But now I have no idea how to convert these command line to c++ program. http://www.wu.ece.ufl.edu/projects/wirelessVideo/project/realTimeCoding/download/doc/howto.pdf